# My new phone isn't listed as a device in the Android Device Manager, how can I register it?

Tags: android-device-manager

I broke my phone a couple weeks ago, thankfully I was paying the $7/mo for insurance and was able to get a replacement in the mail a few days later.  This new phone isn't registered with my Google Play account (https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager?hl=en&u=0 doesn't list it) and I can't remotely install apps through https://play.google.com/store.

Everything else is working fine, it's sync'd with my gmail/chrome just fine and I'm able to install already-paid for applications on it without a problem.  The only thing it seems I *can't* do is install apps remotely through the play.google.com/store website, which makes sense given it's not registered as one of my devices.

Am I missing something obvious?  In the past my devices have always been registered automatically, as best I could tell anyways.